# Multiple packages by weight

Tags: commerce

I'm using Drupal Commerce shipping. I've watched every video and I can not fathom how to effect this everyday shipping rule.

In the real world it is very common for shipping to be priced per package, on the basis of an initial price for the first few kg up to a given weight, plus an additional charge for each kg extra, up to a maximum weight per package. The charges are then recalculated for each additional package. The maximum weight is often dictated by health and safety rules for lifting heavy items.

For example, $10 up to 10 kg, then $1 for each kg extra up to a maximum of 25kg. Rinse and repeat

Assumed is the use of physical_field and please substitute kg for your preferred weight measurement.

Any ideas?